# pip install image doesn't work, pip not recognized, but it is installed

Tags: python, image, cmd, pip, installation

I have python 36. The path is already declared, yet when I enter

```
python pip install image
```

nothing happens, and I am told that pip does not exist. I have install openpyxl before via pip, so I know I have it....but I can't remember how I got it to work.

I recall it being an alternative way of typing it into the CMD that finally made it work.

Typing in a path to the python36 or python .exe file instead of python, the CMD still does not recognize pip

Comment: my hero. works perfect ly thank you.  How come the regular pip install image does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `-m` so that Python will execute the `pip` module, like this:

```
python -m pip install image
```

On Windows, especially if you have multiple versions of Python installed, use the `py` launcher, like this:

```
py -3 -m pip install image
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) for more tips.